# MouseTerm and Terminal.app

Tags: vim, terminal.app

I'm trying to get [MouseTerm](http://bitheap.org/mouseterm/) to work with Terminal.app. I'm on Snow Leopard and followed the install instructions promptly (which are, simply, download the .dmg and run the 'Install' file).

When I start Terminal.app, I still can't use the mouse (specifically in Vim, using `set mouse=a`).

Anyone got it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note:

1. You need [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) to run MouseTerm.
2. Once you've installed SIMBL and MouseTerm and restarted Terminal.app, you'll be able to use your scroll wheel in vim, but no other mouse buttons. They simply aren't implemented in MouseTerm yet.

Comment: I've updated the homepage based on your feedback. It now explicitly mentions that you need to install SIMBL before doing anything else.